# Unable to show value inside alert box, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal, alert

I am trying to show values passed from the controller to my alert box inside my view. 
I have used following code to display but it is not working.

```
@foreach($student as $student)

@include('widgets.alert', array('class'=>'info', 'message'=> 'Creating Bill for: {!!$student->first_name!!}'))
@endforeach
```

If i directly try to show the value like:

```
  @foreach($student as $student)
  <h4>Creating Bill for: {{$student->first_name}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

It works perfectly. Can anyone provide me solution?

Comment: The `@foreach($student as $student)` part doesn't make any sense

Comment: Is there replacement for that? I used coz its the only i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your variables a little bit, because when you run `$student` in a foreach loop it will override the array with all the students.

The easiest way to change it and let it work is this:

Change the first `$student` to `$students`.

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    <h4>Creating Bill for: {{$student->first_name}}</h4>
@endforeach

@foreach($students as $student)
    @include('widgets.alert', array('class'=>'info', 'message'=> 'Creating Bill for: '.$student->first_name))
@endforeach
```

And of course in your `Controller` you need to change the variable that your sending to your `view` from `$student` to `$students`.

Hope this works!

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. It got the same result.
Creating Bill for: <?php echo $student->first_name; ?>.

Comment: Ow now I see, you need to remove the echo when you pass it through, so: 'message' => 'creating bill fir: '.$student->first_name